# MS SQL 2000 or MySQL 5.0?

Tags: asp.net, mysql, sql-server

Which one would you choose for a small ASP.NET 2.0 web site with little traffic? I have no experience with either of them, but my provider wants me to choose one. In fact, I have no experience in ASP.NET too, I am just starting to learn, using VS2008 Professional.

Thank you,
Petr

Answer (score 5):

Use MS SQL, it has better support in Visual Studio, so it will be easier for you to learn. Laso, check if you can get MS SQL 2005 or 2008.

Answer (score 0):

From a performance standpoint, it's probably not going to matter on a site with little traffic.  In your case, I would chose SQL 2000 simply because it will probably integrate better with ASP.NET than MySQL would.

If you had said you were creating the site in PHP, I would have told you to go with MySQL though for the same reason - PHP integrates very well with MySQL.

They are both great databases, it's just a matter of which works better in your particular situation.  That would be SQL 2000 in your case.